# Is it possible execute remove stage using stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute remove file from snowflake internal stage via stored procedure. I'm getting this error:

> Execution error in stored procedure RM_STAGE: Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'UNKNOWN'. At Statement.execute, line 5 position 21

Is it possible to execute remove command via stored procedure?

Many Thanks,
Sriga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. The procedure needs to be a caller’s rights stored procedure. Below is an example of a SP that removes all files from a stage.

````
  create or replace procedure remove_stage_file()
  returns float
  language javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  as     
  $$  
        var my_sql_command = "remove @SPLITSTAGE" ;
        var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
        var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
        return 0;
  $$
  ;```
````

Comment: Mike this was an interesting read: looks like when you define the stored procedure if it is not explicity called as caller or owner, it defaults to the owner's permissions - is this referring to the role permissions that is creating the stored procedure? I also saw: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-stored-procedure-privileges if anyone else is interested.